# Can be ESC connected to battery directly if PDB has not enough power?

Tags: flight-controller, esc, power

I want to use FC Matek F405-TE http://www.mateksys.com/?portfolio=f405-te#tab-id-4 but it's PDB allow only 35A of ESC. I want to use 50-60A ESCs (motors are 40A each) with this controller.

Can I connect ESCs directly to battery instead of PDB? Will the current sensor show correct values in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect the ESC power directly to the battery. This is a similar arrangement to the "4in1 ESC" wiring at the end of the page you linked.

You will not get current measurement. This relies on the power going through the sense resisitor on the FC (black component next to Battery + pad, marked "0m25".)

However, on the Specification page it states it supports "PDB: 4x 35A (Max.4x 50A)" which would suggest 50A ESCs can be used with the board (presumably so long as you are not running them too hard all the time, it can facilitate periodic surges to the full power level.)

Comment: There is Current Sensor pad on the flight controller. How can I use it? Should I put additional sensor between battery and drone and solder it to the this pad?

Comment: That should be possible; the "ArduPilot mapping" tab mentions this is a 0-3.3V input and the "Wiring" tab suggests this maps to a 0-220A range (by default at least - I don't know if this can be changed in software, but a simple potential divider or transistor amplifier could be used to rescale this if needed.)